# impdp on oracle docker setup in Mac OS

Tags: oracle, docker, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to restore an oracle database in mac. So I set up oracle as a docker container in Mac.

1. I'm using this image store/oracle/database-enterprise:12.2.0.1
2. After starting oracle container, I created a folder to copy the `.dmp` files and granted full access to any user (chmod 777).
3. The I copied my `.dmp` files and log file in to that folder. Finally I assigned the folder to `oracle:oinstall` user and group.

Trouble comes with the database setup. I tried 2 methods.

**Method 1**

logged in to oracle server using sqlcl in Mac. And created a user and grant all necessary permissions. Also I created a data pump directory (`MY_PUMP`) and assigned it to the folder that contain `.dmp` files.

When I run `impdp` with this method it says MY_PUMP directory is not available.

**Method 2**

Only this that is different to the method 1 hear is, before creating the user I changed the session.

```
alter session set "_ORACLE_SCRIPT"=true;
```

When I run impdp with this method, It identifies the pump directory but throws lot of errors and fails.

```
impdp \"tom/pass\" DIRECTORY=MY_PUMP FULL=Y DUMPFILE=ttg_01.dmp,ttg_02.dmp LOGFILE=ttg.log

ORA-39083: Object type xxx_SCHEMA failed to create with error:
ORA-31625: Schema userxxx is needed to import this object, but is unaccessible
ORA-01435: user does not exist
Failing sql is:
BEGIN
```

..... etc

Before importing I don't change any databases and only create the user as specified above.

How can I resolve this issue?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As of **Method 1**, here's how it is supposed to be:

- directory should exist in file system (it does)
- a privileged Oracle user - such as `SYS` - should create a *directory* (Oracle object), e.g. `create directory my_pump as 'c:\temp'` (I'm on MS Windows)
- as you already created user (`tom`, right?) who is performing import, you should grant privileges on that directory to that user: `grant read, write on directory my_pump to tom`
  error you got suggests that you might not have done the last step. If that's correct, it is easy to fix it - grant those privileges.